# Смена скорости COM-порта на ходу

Tags: c++, c, rs232, com-port

Необходимость смены скорости на ходу возникла из-за требований к обратной совместимости системы. Контроллер работает на скорости 9600, и особый пакет, отправляемый клиентским приложением, переводит его на скорость 128000. Вот код клиентского приложения (прошу относиться к нему как к псевдокоду, пишу по памяти).

```
m_port.write(modePacket);
m_port.waitForBytesWritten(500);
QThread::msleep(10);
m_port.setBaudRate(128000);
m_port.waitForReadyRead(500);
m_port.readAll();
```

Вот код обработки пакета контроллером:

```
void handleModePacket(int mode)
{
    if (mode == 1) 
        UartInit128000();
    else 
        UartInit9600();
    DelayMS(10);
    SendResponce();
}
```

Собственно, я не хотел бы здесь описывать, что именно не работает в этом коде. Я бы хотел услышать, какие подводные камни могут возникнуть в таком подходе. Можно ли вообще менять скорость таким образом?

Comment: Посмотрите, как работают драйверы Bluetooth UART в Linux. Там именно то и происходит, что вы хотите сделать. Подводные камни кончено будут, если *"что-то пойдёт не так"*.

Comment: @0andriy, где их найти?

Comment: Вот, например, http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/bluetooth/hci_bcm.c Смотрите поля *init_speed = 115200* и *oper_speed = 4000000*. Дальше поднимайтесь по стеку и смотрите как это реализовано.

Answer (score 1):

Почему нет? На мой взгляд никаких проблем не должно быть. Единственное, если перезапустить приложение (некорректное завершение), то скорость в приложении будет 9600, а контроллер останется настроенным на 128000.

Чтобы сохранить совместимость можно сделать по другому:
1. Приложение изначально настраивает СОМ порт на 128000;
2. Отправляет команду проверки скорости;
3. Если приходит правильный ответ - работаем дальше;
4. Если ответа нет - меняем скорость в приложении.